How to use the code type in anylogic databases to change the state of the simulation?
I have a tasklist, which I write into an Anylogic Database. Each row in that table represents one task and includes information such as part, required resources, location, etc. For each task, there are multiple subtasks as well as multiple "on finished" tasks to do. My idea was to write these subtasks and "on finished" tasks as functioncalls directly into the table in one column each, allowing me to have an overview of all of the tasks in one place, instead of writing them into the model logic directly, mainly due to the amount of tasks I have to perform.
As specified above I attempted to write these tasks as code into the table. Then the idea would be to either use the code as a string and call executeAction() or use the code type and CodeValue.execute() to run the code. I am only able to run traceln() from there. Any other actions trying to alter the state of the model result in a root: null error, which I am unable to interpret. I have tried debugging the code I wrote into the table by running it directly in the model as a function. This showed that the function itself works, but once I put it into the database it no longer does.

This is just not a good idea and not good modelling practice. Do not use a database to store code for execution. Use your model to store code for execution and the database for data :)

Hi Benjamin, thank you for the insights, that really does make sense. Do you have any suggestions on how to handle large amounts of tasks to be done (heavily controlled flow). I'm quite afraid of losing the overview of what's going on.
